# Android force Invisible or gone Listview items in update row

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I have `ListView` with some widgets into each row and i can update single row from `Service`. update row work fine but I can not `INVISIBLE` or `GONE` **listview's row items**.

for example my row have `ImageView` and `ProgressBar`. I can not `INVISIBLE` this widgets in this code

```
private void updateView(int download_item_id, int position, int percent, final String stream_filename, final String thumb_path) {
        Log.e("receive: thumb_path: ", thumb_path);
        View v = UI.lv_message_content.getChildAt(position - UI.lv_message_content.getFirstVisiblePosition());
        UI.lv_message_content.getAdapter().getView(position, v, UI.lv_message_content);
        UI.lv_message_content.invalidateViews();
        if (v == null) return;

        ImageView         imgv_image_item   = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imgv_image_item);
        NumberProgressBar numberProgressBar = (NumberProgressBar) v.findViewById(R.id.npb_progressbar);
        ImageView         iv_download_icon  = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.iv_download_icon);
        numberProgressBar.setProgress(percent);

        if (percent == 100) {
            numberProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            iv_download_icon.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }
```

in this code `View.GONE` for `numberProgressBar` and `iv_download_icon` doesnt work if percent equals with 100. i'm testing and debuging code nested `if` work but Gone not set to widgets

Answer (score 0):

I think you missed `notifyDatasetChnaged()`

```
if (percent == 100) {
     numberProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
     iv_download_icon.setVisibility(View.GONE);
     notifyDatasetChanged()
}
```

Comment: not working i'm testing your code with `invalidateViews()`

Answer (score 0):

I'm remove this line and my problem is solved:

```
invalidateViews();
```